# when creating an object inside of an object and then adding to the nested object the console only returns "object" instead of the value added to it

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create some nested objects with values inside of them.
I have the following code:

```
var bob = {name: "Bob Smith", age: 30};
bob.location = 'new florida';
bob.favoriteFood = {};
bob.favoriteFood.american = 'pizza';
bob.favoriteFood.european = 'not pizza';

console.log(bob);
```

however, when i log this to the console, it just returns 'object' at the end.
if i log `console.log(bob.favoriteFood);` then it shows the "favoriteFood"

is this just the console not being able to log nested objects? or is there a problem with my code?

Comment: Try clicking the arrow next to 'Object'. It will expand it into a tree structure where you can view all it's properties. (Assuming you're using chrome)

Comment: doh! that also worked. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use JSON.stringify:

> [JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify): converts a value to JSON notation representing it

```js
var bob = {name: "Bob Smith", age: 30};
bob.location = 'new florida';
bob.favoriteFood = {};
bob.favoriteFood.american = 'pizza';
bob.favoriteFood.european = 'not pizza';

console.log(JSON.stringify(bob));
```